# Unable to update to new version of Gmail

Tags: gmail

My mother’s account is still not updated to the newer version; is still the older version. Under settings, the options are limited to general / accounts / labels / filters / forwarding and POP/IMAP.

The account is inaccessible from PC (IE/FF/Chrome)—it says `invalid username and password`—, but is accessible via an Android device. How do I update it to the newer version?

Answer (score 2):

From what you've mentioned above, you're likely using a "basic" version of Gmail. If you want the "standard" version of Gmail, you can force it to [skip browser check](http://mail.google.com/mail?nocheckbrowser) & load the standard edition.

If it says invalid username/password on desktop but not on your Android device, then ensure you've entered the correct username/password.